# AFNetworking Half the time downloading half the data

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to download a small file, about 5.5kb.

Half of the time it only downloads half of the json, and then of course fails parsing that data. The other half of the time everything works completely normal.

I have a good internet connection.

Im using AFNetworking 2.0. I got it off of the main branch today (1/16/2014).

```
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Physicians/Types/?os=1",BaseUrl] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", operation.responseString);
}];
```

Here is the exact error, but i already know its a parsing error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 4480.) UserInfo=0x15ecd010 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 4480.}
```

This is the sample from their website. And like I said it works half of the time.

#### Do I need to set some sort of chunk size? Is it because their Github page says the current build is failing?

Interestingly enough, it seems to always fail at the exact same point in the file. I can tell this because in the error, I output the response string.

I am not able to reproduce this in any browser, or in my old app which used asihttprequest

***Update 1/28/2014

I downloaded the current version today, which is passing build, and it still fails. When I save out to disk what it does receive it's 5,391 bytes. Again, it fails at the same point each time. In the middle of the work dentist. There aren't any weird characters there.

Comment: Is your server working right? Have you tested it with a rest client?

Comment: yeh, it works with a browser, andriod, wp, and even on the same iphone using asi (my old library). I wanted to move to afnetworking though as its currently supported

Comment: Can you provide the URL you're requesting?

Comment: Is there a way to private message on SO?

Comment: https://services.wellspan.org/Mobile/v3/data.svc/Physicians/Types/?os=1